# Sfml UserControl error when adding it to form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sfml

It seems when I add my user control to my winform it throws this error:

> Failed to create component error. 'SfmlControl'. The error message follows: 'System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'csfml-graphics-2': the specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I get it with this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
//using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MapEditorLib.Classes;

using SFML.System;
using SFML.Window;
using SFML.Graphics;

namespace TileEditor
{
   public partial class SfmlControl : UserControl
    {
        TileSet TileSet;
        RenderTexture RenderTexture;

        //Constructor
        public SfmlControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Events
        protected void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RenderTexture = new RenderTexture((uint)Size.Width, (uint)Size.Height);

            TileSet = new TileSet();
            TileSet.Load("C:\\Users\\Shadowblitz16\\Desktop\\LinkBank1_S.png");
        }
        protected void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            RenderTexture.Clear(Color.Black);
            RenderTexture.Display();
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem comes from me not including the dlls directly in the root of the project. However I don't want to do this, because it clutters the project and makes navigating harder.

I was wondering if there was a easy way to relocate them to my project directory under a 'Library' folder or if this was even related to the dlls.